# C# How go through a text file to find a specific value

Tags: c#, text

I was trying to figure out how to go through a text file where the contents are formatted like this:

```
Date: 7/30/2013 12:00:00 AM 
Source Path: C:\FileMoveResults 
Destination Path: C:\Users\Documents\.NET Development\testing\ 
Last Folder Updated: 11.0.25.1
```

Where I could search it depending on the "Last Folder Updated" and store the source path and destination path in seperate variables.

How would one go about doing this?

Thanks!

Edit:

Here is the code I currently have which doesnt work since i'm getting the error that "foreach doesn't support bool"

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(GlobalVars.strLogPath))
{
foreach (var items in File.ReadLines(GlobalVars.strLogPath))
{
foreach(var item in items.StartsWith("Destination Path: "))
{
//nothing here yet
```

Comment: What have you tried? At its very simplest, you can read each line and use the `String.StartsWith` method to find the lines you're looking for and store them in some class/variables.

Comment: Actually, I did try that in a foreach statement. This is what I currently have: using (var reader = new StreamReader(GlobalVars.strLogPath)) { foreach (var items in File.ReadLines(GlobalVars.strLogPath)) { foreach(var item in items.StartsWith("Destination Path: ")) { }


Wow thats a terrible format, ill put it up in my question. Never the less its giving me an error that foreach doesn't operate on "bool" variables...

Comment: "for each line" is maybe not the best solution if you want to read a whole entry (= "for each <4 lines at once>")

Answer (score 4):

- Read 4 lines a time
- Parse the last line (last folder updated)
- Check if you want to store the entry
- If yes -> store line 2 and line 3
- Repeat until no more lines available

Edit: Reflecting your new question about your code:

Remove the innermost foreach loop and rename "items" to "oneSingleLine" - this should make it more clear where your error resides. Maybe create a new question as this is not a discussion board.

Comment: I should be coding this where more entries in the text file could be made. Therefore, who knows how many lines this thing will end up with.

Comment: This is why "repeat until no more lines available" should be a loop and not copy&paste of code :-)

Comment: I appreicate the help. However, how is this a discussion board when i'm asking a question? I'm not sure of the difference since i'm fairly new to posting.

Comment: I am not sure how well this solution will stand up when you start running into spaces / potential text that could be an issue.  I would try a little different approach.  I would most likely read one line at a time until I found Source Path:.  I would then store that line, and the next line in two variables.  I would then inspect the third line - and based on inspection would then choose to handle the stored variables.  This will account for irregularities / formatting  changes in the file.

Comment: Yep, building up a state machine is probably a better and more robust approach, however, I don't know exactly if our OP is up to such patterns already ;-)

Comment: @user2619395: SO is about asking specific questions, not so much about collaboratively building up your code if you're a beginner (just my experience so far). Maybe a discussion board (forum) is more suited for your question.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking something like this.  It's a little more complicated but will help ensure if your file's format changes you should still be able to loop through and find each set of values.

```
    public void ReadFile(string filepath)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> mypaths = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        string line;
        string line1 = null;
        string line2 = null;
        bool store = false;
        using(var rdr = new StreamReader(filepath))
        {
            while((line = rdr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if(store = false && line.ToLower().Contains("source path:"))
                {
                    line1 = line;
                    store = true;
                }
                else if (store = true && line.ToLower().Contains("destination path:"))
                {
                    line2 = line;
                }
                else if (line.ToLower().Contains("last folder updated:"))
                {
                    var myvaluetoinspect = line;
                    if(1==1) // my condition
                    {
                        mypaths.Add(line1, line2);
                    }
                    // Clear and start over
                    store = false;
                    line1 = null;
                    line2 = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    store = false;
                    line1 = null;
                    line2 = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually I started recoding it to something like this. I'll let you know if it works/how it turns out! :D

Comment: The .tolower() is a nice touch, didn't think about that!

Comment: Just a quick question for the line: while((line = rdr.ReadLine()) != null what does "!=null" do? (clearly i know what a not equals null, im not that big of a noob, is just wondering what it is for exactly in this case)

Edit: Nevermind, stupid question, figured it out XD

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example of how it can be done.
There is plenty of room for improvement here in the areas of handling badly formatted lines etc..

```
    static void ReadFile(string path)
    {
        var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();
        var infos = new List<TextFileInfo>();

        var info = new TextFileInfo();
        var currentLine = 0;
        while (lines.Count > 0)
        {
            TryReadLine(lines[0], info);

            if (currentLine++ >= 3)
            {
                currentLine = 0;
                infos.Add(info);
                info = new TextFileInfo();
            }

            lines.RemoveAt(0);
        }

        //Do something with infos
        // return infos;
   }

    public static void TryReadLine(string line, TextFileInfo info)
    {
        if (line.StartsWith(DateTag))
        {
            var value = line.Replace(DateTag, string.Empty).Trim();
            info.Date = DateTime.Parse(value);

            return;
        }

        if (line.StartsWith(SourcePathTag))
        {
            var value = line.Replace(SourcePathTag, string.Empty).Trim();
            info.SourcePath = value;

            return;
        }

        if (line.StartsWith(DestinationPathTag))
        {
            var value = line.Replace(SourcePathTag, string.Empty).Trim();
            info.DestinationPath = value;

            return;
        }

        if (line.StartsWith(LastFolderUpdatedTag))
        {
            var value = line.Replace(SourcePathTag, string.Empty).Trim();
            info.LastFolderUpdated = value;

            return;
        }

        throw new Exception("Invalid line encountered");
    }

    public class TextFileInfo
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string SourcePath { get; set; }
        public string DestinationPath { get; set; }
        public string LastFolderUpdated { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample starter for how to do it with LINQ.  I used [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to play with the code.

```
    var input = "Date: 7/30/2013 12:00:00 AM\nSource Path: C:\\FileMoveResults\nDestination Path: C:\\Users\\Documents\\.NET Development\\testing\\ \nLast Folder Updated: 11.0.25.1 \nDate: 7/30/2013 12:00:00 AM\nSource Path: C:\\FileMoveResults\nDestination Path: C:\\Users\\Documents\\.NET Development\\testing\\ \nLast Folder Updated: 11.0.25.1 \nDate: 7/30/2013 12:00:00 AM\nSource Path: C:\\FileMoveResults\nDestination Path: C:\\Users\\Documents\\.NET Development\\testing\\ \nLast Folder Updated: 11.0.25.1 \nDate: 7/30/2013 12:00:00 AM\nSource Path: C:\\FileMoveResults\nDestination Path: C:\\Users\\Documents\\.NET Development\\testing\\ \nLast Folder Updated: 11.0.25.1 \nDate: 7/30/2013 12:00:00 AM\nSource Path: C:\\FileMoveResults\nDestination Path: C:\\Users\\Documents\\.NET Development\\testing\\ \nLast Folder Updated: 11.0.25.1 \nDate: 7/30/2013 12:00:00 AM\nSource Path: C:\\FileMoveResults\nDestination Path: C:\\Users\\Documents\\.NET Development\\testing\\ \nLast Folder Updated: 11.0.25.1 \nDate: 7/30/2013 12:00:00 AM\nSource Path: C:\\FileMoveResults\nDestination Path: C:\\Users\\Documents\\.NET Development\\testing\\ \nLast Folder Updated: 11.0.25.1 \nDate: 7/30/2013 12:00:00 AM\nSource Path: C:\\FileMoveResults\nDestination Path: C:\\Users\\Documents\\.NET Development\\testing\\ \nLast Folder Updated: 11.0.25.1 \nDate: 7/30/2013 12:00:00 AM\nSource Path: C:\\FileMoveResults\nDestination Path: C:\\Users\\Documents\\.NET Development\\testing\\ \nLast Folder Updated: 11.0.25.1";

string[] lines = null;
using(var reader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input))))
{
    lines = reader.ReadToEnd().Split('\n');
}

IList<Tuple<string, string>> paths = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
if(lines != null)
{
    const int TAKE = 4;

    var position = 0;

    while(position < lines.Length)
    {
        var currentLines = lines.Skip(position).Take(TAKE);
        paths.Add(Tuple.Create(currentLines.ElementAt(1).Replace("Source Path: ", string.Empty), currentLines.ElementAt(2).Replace("Destination Path: ", string.Empty)));
        position = (position + TAKE);
    }
}

paths.Dump("Result");
```

What I did was gather all of the source and destination paths. You can modifiy this to only store the ones you want based on your search criteria.

Result looks like this, granted I just copied your example over and over so there is no variation in path names:

[image]

I would probably also make the Tuple of type `Tuple<DictionaryInfo, DictionaryInfo>` if you want to have move and copy abilities built into your objects.